# Thumbnail creator in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a collection of large size images. I'm showing them in my website. But I don't want to show the actual image first.. instead I want to show it's thumbnail. When A web user clicks on that image, then I want to show actual image in a popup.
Here my problem is I don't want to have a copy of each image(1 for thumbnail and other for popup) in my server. Just I want to resize(make it smaller so that the image size should reduce to less than 50 KB) image before it is loading on the browser and should show as a thumbnail. Please let me know if there is any plugin for this question in angular 2

Comment: you need serverside code cause resizing on client side(angular) will basically load your image first

Comment: Thank you for you reply, If we search for an image in google, first it will show thumbnails and then when we click on it, it shows actual image. I don't think there will be a copy for every image. Please suggest

Comment: @maheshpeddi: I suspect there is a copy (faster), but even if there wouldn't be they would still first resize it on server - for example look in networking on a google image search - you'll see it loads thumbnail size like https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:XXXXXXXX

Comment: Actually I think that they are coding to generate a thumbnail so that it will take lesser time to load on the browser so it is showing like some encripted URL. Otherwise they couldn't do that and directly they could show actual image. Please suggest me that how can we generate that thumbnail file

Comment: Please suggest me.